# SQL Trace : How to capture only Insert,Update,Delete statements using SQL Server Profiler?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-profiler

Requirement :

I need to capture only Insert,Update and Delete statements in trace. For this I used the below trace code but unfortunately its capturing stored procedures execution,declare statements where there are no DMLs in that execution.

What do I need to do to capture only Insert,Update and Delete statements only.
Help is appreciated.

```
declare @rc int
declare @TraceID int
declare @maxfilesize bigint
set @maxfilesize = 5 

exec @rc = sp_trace_create @TraceID output, 0, N'InsertFileNameHere', @maxfilesize, NULL 
if (@rc != 0) goto error

declare @on bit
set @on = 1
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 15, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 17, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 18, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 15, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 17, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 18, @on

declare @intfilter int
declare @bigintfilter bigint

exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 0, 6, N'%INSERT%'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 1, 6, N'%UPDATE%'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 1, 6, N'%DELETE%'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 0, 1, NULL
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 10, 0, 7, N'SQL Server Profiler - 19bdcc9e-99de-4173-99e7-84cd5fc0add4'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 10, 0, 1, NULL

exec sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1


select TraceID=@TraceID
goto finish

error: 
select ErrorCode=@rc

finish: 
go
```

Comment: add `exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 1, @on`

Comment: Thanks Rohit for your reply but unfortunately still its capturing declare as well as exec statements.

Comment: Include `RPC:Completed` event also and use `OR` condition for starting three conditions. <br/> `exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 1, @on` <br/> and <br/> `exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 1, 6, N'%INSERT%'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 1, 6, N'%UPDATE%'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 1, 6, N'%DELETE%'`

Comment: I already included RPC completed. could you please modify my code and paste here .

Answer (score 1):

Please try below script to capture required data:

```
    declare @rc int
declare @TraceID int
declare @maxfilesize bigint
set @maxfilesize = 5 

exec @rc = sp_trace_create @TraceID output, 0, N'InsertFileNameHere', @maxfilesize, NULL 
if (@rc != 0) goto error

declare @on bit
set @on = 1

exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 15, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 17, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 18, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 15, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 17, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 18, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 1, @on

declare @intfilter int
declare @bigintfilter bigint

exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 1, 6, N'%INSERT%'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 1, 6, N'%UPDATE%'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 1, 6, N'%DELETE%'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 0, 1, NULL
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 10, 0, 7, N'SQL Server Profiler - 19bdcc9e-99de-4173-99e7-84cd5fc0add4'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 10, 0, 1, NULL

exec sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1


select TraceID=@TraceID
goto finish

error: 
select ErrorCode=@rc

finish: 
go
```

Comment: Thanks alot Rohit.I am not sure why still its capturing sp_compare,declare,@0utput='select id from test'  etc.